# Нагрузочные тесты k6 в Docker

Tags: docker, chromium

Написал нагрузочные тесты (k6-browser), локально все проходит без проблем. Возникла ситуация, необходим запуск через gitlab ci/cd, раннер на другой машине и при загрузке страницы в режиме headless=false возникает ошибка с WebGL "Что-то пошло не так, перезагрузите позже....",

Текст ошибки:
`level=error msg="{\"message\":\"Failed to obtain WebGL context\",\"stack\":\"Error: Failed to obtain WebGL context\\n    at new b….groupstp.ru/static/js/main.5dca8f2c.js:2:879632)\"}" browser_source=console-api source=browser`

Пробовал через K6_BROWSER_ARGS прописывать агрументы use-angle, disable-gpu и прочие, не помогает

Что можно предпринять или где можно почитать больше про проблему, не могу настройть

Конфиг компьютера

```
Acer Swift
Процессор  11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz   2.42 GHz
Оперативная память  16,0 ГБ (доступно: 15,8 ГБ)
Производитель видеокарты Intel
Модель видеокарты Iris Xe Graphics
```

before_script gitlab ci gonfig (image: node)

```
        - gpg -k
        - gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/k6-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C5AD17C747E3415A3642D57D77C6C491D6AC1D69
        - echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/k6-archive-keyring.gpg] https://dl.k6.io/deb stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/k6.list
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get install -y k6 chromium gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils
        - k6 --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Помогла установка больших зависимостей и `google-chrome-stable`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ffmpeg \
    libnss3 \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libasound2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libxt6 \
    libxss1 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxrender1 \
    libfreetype6 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libappindicator3-1 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    unzip \
    xdg-utils

RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -qO- https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb > /tmp/chrome.deb
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/chrome.deb; apt-get -fy install
```